# CALayer subclass not animating to property changes

Tags: ios, calayer, caanimation

I have a `CALayer` subclass with float `animAngle` as property marked as `@dynamic`. I have implemented methods `actionForKey`, `initWithLayer`, `needsDisplayForKey` and `drawInContext` for subclass.
The definition for `actionForKey` is as follows

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NString *)event {
    if([event isEqualToString:@"animAngle"]) {
        return [self animationForKey:event];
    }
    return [super actionForKey:event];
}
```

And

```
- (CABasicAnimation *)animationForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSString *animValue = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key];// Logs as 0
    CABasicAnimation *anim;

    if([key isEqualToString:@"animAngle"]) {
        anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
        anim.autoreverses = YES;
        //anim.fromValue = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key]; // setting animation value from layer property as in here does not work.
        anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f];            // This works
    }
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    anim.duration = 0.11;
    return anim;
}
```

In Someother class:

```
myCASublayer.animAngle = 0.5f;
```

Somehow the `CABasicAnimation` being returned is not able to properly use the layer "`animAngle`" property. 
What would i be possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: One is called `animAngle` the other is `wiggleAngle`

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: Sorry that was a typo. Its animAngle.

Comment: @basstrekerk87, better copy/paste next time, saves errors! You know you don't actually have to indent code manually? Use the button or start with 3 backquotes (`)

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: Did use add code button, still misaligned the code somehow. will get better at it

Comment: i still am banging my head around this. can somebody help here!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CocoaHeads Session: Rob Napier on Animating Custom Layer Properties](http://vimeo.com/44986916) is a good presentation about custom animations.

CALayers hate do draw ;)

Comment: thanks, it works. but if the animation is infinite in repeat count, it gives only animates once. Is drawInContext not called for repeated animations?

Comment: @basstrekker87 I'm not sure if action for key can support repeating. AFAIK it's more  or less an implicit animation from an old value to a new value.

Answer (score 1):

If `animAngle` is a `@property` - you must specify `accessors` for this property. 
When you mark property as `@dynamic` this means, that you will provide an implementation of those methods dynamically at runtime. So, if you do not provide accessors for property, you can't access it.

Comment: tried creating accessors for animAngle but still not working. @dynamic is required for CALayer subclasses which provides implementations for the property itself, but anyhows changes are still not getting updated

Comment: That is not really true for CALayers. They are ... "special" ;)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Whats untrue. the answer by Lexandr or the comment i added.

Comment: @basstrekker87 The code was targeted at the answer, otherwise I would have used @ reply like you did and like this comment does. Layers generate their own accessors and can have any object set using setValue:forKey even though it may not even be a property on CALayer.